# Upgrade SQLite database in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am making one android app where I am using `SQLite` database. I have already released one version of it and now for second and third version suppose I require to change in the database table like adding/removing fields.

So How can I handle this upgrade in Android. Here I don't want to drop the complete table like stuff, Here it should use `Alter` to update the tables.

Suppose user has installed my first version of my application then after few days I released next version `1.1` with changes in database table - added one field and here user did not upgrade it and meanwhile I again released the `1.2` again added one more field

So here How I could handle this situation when this user upgrade my application from Version `1` to Version `1.2`, where Version `1.1` is missed and attribute which I added is also missed that can create problems.

Any solution to handle this ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using `SQLiteOpenHelper`, just increment the database version number for any to-be-released version with database schema changes. In case there's an older database file around, your `onUpgrade()` will be called so you can migrate the database from any old version.

For example, if your 1.0 database version is 1, 1.1 is 2 and 1.2 is 3 and the user is updating version 1.0 to 1.2. `onUpgrade()` is called with `oldVersion` set to 1 and `newVersion` set to 3. From these version numbers your code can figure out what needs to be done, like:

```
@Override public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    switch (oldVersion) {
        case 1:
        updateFrom1To2(db);

        case 2: // fall-through
        updateFrom2To3(db);

        break;

        default:
        Assert.fail("You forgot to write code for oldVersion " + oldVersion);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I know this but So here How I could handle this situation when this user upgrade my application from Version 1 to Version 1.2, where Version 1.1 is missed and attribute which I added in that version is also missed that can create problems. What code should I write to handle this situation when user upgrade from version 1 to 1.3 and version 1.2 to 1.3

Comment: Just write the `onUpgrade()` code so that it can migrate any old version to current.

Comment: You'll have to design your db architecture the way that it will be convenient enough to upgrade from X to Y while there are Z versions between them.

Comment: Suppose in version 1.1 I add one `ALTER TABLE TABLE_SECRET ADD COLUMN    "attr1" INTEGER;` and next version 1.2 I add this  `ALTER TABLE TABLE_SECRET ADD COLUMN "attr2" INTEGER;`, so here If user upgrade from 1 to 1.3 then it will create issues because `attr1` has not added

Comment: so ALTER - ADD 2 columns :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do anything you want in `onUpgrade` in sqldb
. You can use `ALTER` to add new columns to your table.

Worst case, if your schema is completely and entirely different, you'll have to create the new table, populate it using data from the old table, and then delete the old table.

In any case, `onUpgrade` was designed to allow for a smooth upgrade without any loss of data. It's just up to you to implement it properly.
You should put all changes in your onUpgrade method you can use this code:

```
@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    String sql = "ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_SECRET + " ADD COLUMN " +
     "name_of_column_to_be_added" + " INTEGER";
    db.execSQL(sql);        
}
```

for more look [this](http://joshhendo.com/2012/03/android-sqlite-database-upgrade/)

**EDIT**

> This is a nice thought and i found one solution(not tested), you need
>   to check the update ,example -  Check for the ALTER you have done  in 1.1 in the
>   version  1.2  by reading the db rows or some thing , if it
>   is not there, you want to Alter this too with the 1.2 alter .

Comment: Yes I know this but my question is different, read it again seriously - "So here How I could handle this situation when this user upgrade my application from Version 1 to Version 1.2, where Version 1.1 is missed and attribute which I added is also missed that can create problems." - What code should I write to handle this situation when user upgrade from version 1 to 1.3 and version 1.2 to 1.3

Comment: how you think Version 1 to Version 1.2 where Version 1.1 is missed make a problem?From my thoughts there is all the thing which you want in 1.2. then why you bother about 1.1

Comment: i am sorry to telling this but, this is not a good practice , changing the DB regularly, design one DB and ensure that will be perfect and a least chance for modification

Comment: Suppose in version 1.1 I add one ALTER TABLE TABLE_SECRET ADD COLUMN    "attr1" INTEGER; and next version 1.2 I add this  ALTER TABLE TABLE_SECRET ADD COLUMN "attr2" INTEGER;, so here If user upgrade from 1 to 1.3 then it will create issues because attr1 has not added

Answer (score 0):

I usually follow a different kind of implementation to onUpgrade method to support backward compatibility in databases.

Note: Here I only show implementation to add more columns in the latest database versions.

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    //  1.  Copy the database file to temproary file.
    //  2.  Drop all the old tables from db
    //            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + <TABLE NAME> );
    //  3.  Create tables using new Schema
    //            this.onCreate(db);
    //  4. Copy the data from temproary file to new db
    //  5. Remove the temprorary file
}
```

It is more convenient for me to use this kind of implementation than using ALTER commands.